# POST request to get access token from keycloak gives 404 bad credentials - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, keycloak

I am trying to connect RestApi created with SpringBoot to get access token from Keycloak.

This is the code I have:

**Application.yml**

```
keycloak:
  realm: ${CLIENT_RELM_NAME:registerApiRealm}
  auth-server-url: ${KEYCLOAK_URL_WITH_PATH:http://localhost:8080/auth}
  ssl-required: external
  #keycloak resource is the client ID
  resource: ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_NAME:registerApiClienty}
  #replace secret with your key
  credentials:
    secret: ${CLIENT_RELM_SECRET:12a658ea-b728-4f53-9948-492ef470363f}
  #The line below will prevent redirect to login page
  bearer-only: true
```

**KeycloakServiceImpl.java**

```
    @Component
    public class KeyCloakServiceImpl implements KeyCloakService {
    
        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegistrationController.class);
    
        @Value("${keycloak.credentials.secret}")
        private String SECRETKEY;
    
        @Value("${keycloak.resource}")
        private String CLIENTID;
    
        @Value("${keycloak.auth-server-url}")
        private String AUTHURL;
    
        @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
        private String REALM;
    
        @Value("${admin.username}")
        private String ADMIN_USERNAME;
    
        @Value("${admin.password}")
        private String ADMIN_PASSWORD;
    
        @Autowired
        RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    
        @Override
        public TokenDto getToken(UserCredentials userCredentials) {
    
            TokenDto responseToken = null;
            try {
    
                MultiValueMap<String, String> urlParameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
                urlParameters.add("grant_type", "password");
                urlParameters.add("client_id", CLIENTID);
                urlParameters.add("username", userCredentials.getUsername());
                urlParameters.add("password", userCredentials.getPassword());
                urlParameters.add("client_secret", SECRETKEY);
    
                responseToken = authenticate(urlParameters);
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            return responseToken;
    
        }

 private TokenDto authenticate( MultiValueMap<String, String> urlParameters ) throws Exception {

        TokenDto tokenDto = new TokenDto();

        String uri = AUTHURL + "/realms/" + REALM + "/protocol/openid-connect/token";

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(urlParameters, httpHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<Object> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, Object.class);
        log.info("{}", result);
        log.info("{}", result.getBody());

        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) result.getBody();

        if (map != null) {
            tokenDto.setAccess_token(map.get("access_token").toString());
            tokenDto.setToken_type(map.get("token_type").toString());
            tokenDto.setRefresh_token(map.get("refresh_token").toString());
            tokenDto.setExpires_in(map.get("expires_in").toString());
            tokenDto.setScope(map.get("scope").toString());
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return tokenDto;

    }
```

When I test it with `Postaman` by sending `username` and `password``

```
{
    "username": "user",
    "password": "useruser35"
  
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: [{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client credentials"}]
```

I am not sure why I double-checked if my user is created and it is, I checked clientId and secret and everything seems fine.

What am I missing here, any advice appreciated.

Comment: try changing this permission in keycloak server->clientid 
Access Type = public

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be valid.

You might want to check out [this](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/01/29/api-login-and-jwt-token-generation-using-keycloak#test_your_new_client) manual to see if keycloak has been properly configured.

The password grant flow in your example is usually not the preferred approach for doing signons.
You can also retrieve the token via spring security, see [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2Client-authorized-repo-service). There are many examples on the internet of how to do oAuth2 with spring security.